# Adding cypress test framework to Maven pom.xml

Tags: maven, cypress

Trying to use the new cypress framework with a maven project - the documentation has only an npm module setup example (npm install cypress) and a package.json usage example.

How would this be converted to usage in a maven dependency?

Comment: Were you able to integrate cypress.io into your maven project? If yes please share how. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also download Cypress directly without `npm`.

There are instructions as well as the direct download [here](https://on.cypress.io/installing-cypress#Direct-Download).

Answer (score 3):

Here's a [great article](https://www.wimdeblauwe.com/blog/2019/2019-06-15-running-cypress-tests-with-testcontainers-for-a-spring-boot-with-thymeleaf-application/) on using maven to run Cypress tests.
You should be able to use a [Docker container](https://hub.docker.com/u/cypress) for Cypress via the maven [Testcontainers](https://www.testcontainers.org/) plugin.

Comment: [Searching for "cypress" at testcontainers.com](https://testcontainers.com/modules/?_gl=1*1a33etg*_up*MQ..*_ga*MTY4NzY5MDkzNS4xNzA4NTAzMzU1*_ga_22TYV8FBPD*MTcwODUwMzM1Mi4xLjAuMTcwODUwMzM1Mi4wLjAuMA..&s=cypress): _No modules found_. [Searching for "maven" at testcontainers.com](https://testcontainers.com/modules/?_gl=1*1a33etg*_up*MQ..*_ga*MTY4NzY5MDkzNS4xNzA4NTAzMzU1*_ga_22TYV8FBPD*MTcwODUwMzM1Mi4xLjAuMTcwODUwMzM1Mi4wLjAuMA..&s=maven): _No modules found_.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [good article](https://www.wimdeblauwe.com/blog/2019/2019-06-15-running-cypress-tests-with-testcontainers-for-a-spring-boot-with-thymeleaf-application/) that allows you to execute cypress tests as a part of mvn build, so you can have your backend app up and running during the cypress testing. But I did a slight change because the solution in the article doesn't take any feedback about tests execution into consideration. So, this is what I've changed:

Container creation part:

```
    @SneakyThrows
    @NotNull
    private GenericContainer<?> createCypressContainer()
    {

        var container = new GenericContainer<>(DockerImageName.parse("cypress/included:3.4.0"));

        container.withClasspathResourceMapping("e2e", "/e2e", BindMode.READ_WRITE);
        container.setWorkingDirectory("/e2e");
        container.withCreateContainerCmdModifier(it -> it.withEntrypoint("cypress", "open").withWorkingDir("/e2e"));
        container.addEnv("CYPRESS_baseUrl", "http://host.testcontainers.internal:" + port);
        return container;
    }
```

Test execution and results evaluation:

```
 @Test
    public void runCypressTests() throws InterruptedException, IOException
    {
        Testcontainers.exposeHostPorts(port);

        try (GenericContainer<?> container = createCypressContainer()) {
            container.start();
            Container.ExecResult execResult = container.execInContainer("/bin/sh", "-c", "cypress run");
            log.warn(execResult.getStdout());
            assertEquals("End to end tests are failed. Execution exit code returned non 0 value",
                0, execResult.getExitCode());
        }
    }
```